# How to test that dispatch only gets called once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I have a custom hook that dispatches an action when a URL parameter changes:

```
export const useUser = (): void => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user } = useParams<{ user: string }>();

  useEffect(() => {dispatch(getUser(user));
  }, [dispatch, user]);
};
```

I have a test that mocks `useDispatch` and `useParams`:

```
const dispatch = jest.fn();

const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, 'useDispatch').mockImplementation(() => {
  return dispatch;
});

const useParamsSpy = jest.spyOn(reactRouter, 'useParams').mockImplementation(() => {
  return { user: 'test' };
});

const getUserSpy = jest.spyOn(slice, 'getUser');

renderHook(() => useRequestProfile());

expect(getUserSpy.mock.calls).toEqual([['test']]);
```

Now, this works, in that I can determine that `getUser('test')` has been called, but the point of wrapping it in `useEffect` is to make sure that it only get's called *once*. How can I test this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `useUser` hook inside a component. Pass some props to this component and check. Later, pass the new props to re-render the component and check again if `getUserSpy` was called more than once.

Besides, we use `MemoryRouter` with initial entries instead of mocking `useParams` to provide URL parameters.

The expected result of our test is: regardless of how many times the component rendering, due to `dispatch` and `user` parameter are stable, the `useEffect` in the `useUser` hook will only be executed once.

E.g.

`useUser.ts`:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as slice from './slice';

export const useUser = (): void => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user } = useParams<{ user: string }>();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(slice.getUser(user));
  }, [dispatch, user]);
};
```

`slice.ts`:

```
export const getUser = (user) => ({ type: 'GET_USER', payload: user });
```

`useUser.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import * as slice from './slice';
import { useUser } from './useUser';

describe('useUser', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const getUserSpy = jest.spyOn(slice, 'getUser');
    function TestComp(props) {
      console.log(props);
      useUser();
      return null;
    }
    const store = createStore(() => ({}));

    const { rerender } = renderHook(TestComp, {
      initialProps: { data: '1' },
      wrapper: ({ children }) => (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/test']}>
            <Route path="/:user">{children}</Route>
          </MemoryRouter>
        </Provider>
      ),
    });
    expect(getUserSpy).toBeCalledWith('test');
    rerender({ data: '2' });
    expect(getUserSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/70928091/useUser.test.tsx (7.748 s)
  useUser
    ✓ should pass (39 ms)

  console.log
    { data: '1' }

      at TestComp (stackoverflow/70928091/useUser.test.tsx:14:15)

  console.log
    { data: '2' }

      at TestComp (stackoverflow/70928091/useUser.test.tsx:14:15)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 slice.ts   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 useUser.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.253 s, estimated 9 s
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [toHaveBeenCalledTimes](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber) matcher.

```
expect(getUserSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```